# subclassing collections.abc.MutableMapping - update method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand subclassing of `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. I've created my own version of `dict` that prints some info:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class MutableMappingTest(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__', args, kwargs)
        self.my_store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print('__getitem__:', key)
        return self.my_store[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('__setitem__:', key, value)
        self.my_store[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print('__delitem__:', key)
        del self.my_store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        print('__iter__')
        return iter(self.my_store)

    def __len__(self):
        print('__len__')
        return len(self.my_store)
```

What I do not understand: When I update by assigning to a nested attribute, `__setitem__` is not called, just `__getitem__`:

```
>>> t = MutableMappingTest(test={"deep": "foo"})
__init__ () {'test': {'deep': 'foo'}}
__setitem__: test {'deep': 'foo'}
>>> t['test']['deep'] = 'bar'
__getitem__: test
```

How can I also hook into updating nested attributes. Do I have to override update()? How is that done?

Comment: The thing `test` maps to isn't another `MutableMappingTest` object; it's a regular dict. There are no nested attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not setting an item in `t`.  Instead, you're getting a regular dictionary from `t`, and then setting an item in that dictionary.

If you want the sub dictionaries to behave like `MutableMappingTest` objects, you have to make them `MutableMappingTest` objects.

```
>>> t = MutableMappingTest(test=MutableMappingTest(deep="foo"))
__init__ () {'deep': 'foo'}
__setitem__: deep foo
__init__ () {'test': <__main__.MutableMappingTest object at 0x000001EA3C1DDB00>}
__setitem__: test <__main__.MutableMappingTest object at 0x000001EA3C1DDB00>
>>> t['test']['deep'] = 'bar'
__getitem__: test
__setitem__: deep bar
```

Comment: ok that makes perfect sense. How could I print out the updated content of `my_store` after the update is done, without explicitly calling another method. So if this is done in MutableMappings `update`, could I wrap that method?